# powershell script move emails from inbox to archive upon after reworking (lotus notes)

Tags: powershell, move, archive, lotus

For a certain time I was struggling to write a powershell script which will read e-mails from inbox by 'Title' and I succeed it. After that I am using ForEach and so on.

Now I want to move all my e-mails from inbox to archive (not to new folder which calls 'Archive' but the real 'Archive'). Someone can help? Thanks

Down below it can be found my code for the first mentioned activity (read e-mails)

````
"if([Environment]::Is64BitProcess -eq $true)" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "{    BREAK    } " + Environment.NewLine + 
           " else {     } " + Environment.NewLine +
"$strUserView = '$Inbox'"   + Environment.NewLine +
"$DomServer = 'YC1COBBOED2/SRV/SPAR/De'"   + Environment.NewLine + 
"$DomDBPath = 'mail\user.nsf'"   + Environment.NewLine +
"$pwd4NotesDB = " + PWD   + Environment.NewLine +
"$ipPath2Export = 'C:\Temp' "  + Environment.NewLine +
"$DomSession = New-Object -ComObject Lotus.NotesSession #Use LN COM Class"  + Environment.NewLine +
"$DomSession.Initialize($pwd4NotesDB) #This Is When Lotus asks For your password When you open it"  + Environment.NewLine +
"$DomDatabase = $DomSession.GetDatabase($DomServer,$DomDBPath) "  + Environment.NewLine +
"$DomView  = $DomDatabase.GetView($strUserView) #Initialize View "  + Environment.NewLine +
"$Counterf = $DomView.GetFirstDocument() #Define first document in view"+ Environment.NewLine +
"    $data = @()"+ Environment.NewLine +
"While ($CounterF -ne $nul) {" + Environment.NewLine +
"$DomNexDocument = $DomView.GetNextDocument($CounterF) #Define Next doc" + Environment.NewLine +
"#Define some fields"+ Environment.NewLine +
"$DomeLoopSubject = $CounterF.GetItemValue('Subject') #GetSubject"+ Environment.NewLine +
"$data += $DomeLoopSubject" + Environment.NewLine +
"$CounterF.PutInFolder('IDNow-Archiv') " 
+ Environment.NewLine +
"$CounterF = $DomNexDocument #Raise counter"+ Environment.NewLine +
"} "
+ Environment.NewLine +
"$data | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test1.csv'"+ Environment.NewLine +
"return $data"```


Thanks
````

Comment: Archiving is a process that runs entirely on a Notes client or on the server, and it doesn't require programming. For example, older mails from my mail database are automatically archived every night, by the server. So I think I don't really understand your question. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I know what agent can do (task scheduling etc.), but i am programming a robot that will do the same thing, and i want to write a ps which will allow robot to do the same. That is why i am seraching for solution.

Comment: I want that robot can make the same thing as lotus admin trough schedule tasks independently.

Comment: In the background of all activities of any application there is a code, with the help of which certain actions / activities can also be performed. Similar to what I mentioned above, there is certainly a code that performs actions that enable the activities listed in my query. I hope my question is a little bit clearer now? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure if I understand... There are agents that can be scheduled, but they are inside an application. You can Enable or Disable agents, but I think it is not possible to do that using PowerShell. What you can do is: write an agent in a separate database that enables or disables agents, and then write something in PowerShell that calls that a web-agent with some parameters. The agent then uses these parameters to enable or disable agents in other applications. Does this help you a little?

Comment: Yes, you have perfectly understand. The idea was, somehow to "trigger" the agent without using Archive/settings plan inside IBM Notes, rather to write a code which will "call" an agent which will perform archiving activities according to the set parameters.

Comment: I am also on the trail of Your idea, unfortunately I have a problem with realization:-)